# Style text inside a 'textarea'

Tags: html, css, textarea, margin

I'm working in this form. Its design is exactly like this:

[image]

Right now I'm at this stage, so I am working on some little details:

[image]

As you will be able to see, the "Your text..." is stuck to the top left corner of the [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). I'm trying to find a way to manipulate this via CSS if possible. I just need to apply some margin/padding to the text inside the *textarea*. If this is not possible with CSS I'm open for suggestions.

How can I manipulate the text inside the textarea via CSS?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use CSS `padding` property:

```
textarea {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Is padding supported on all browsers? Also mobile? I have had issues with the input text not showing because of padding issues...

Answer (score 26):

Use:

```css
textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*Note*: box-sizing is a CSS 3 property. It's very useful, because without it width: 100% or other will not work as you expected.

Comment: Doesn't mess with the overall width of the box. Only Correct answer. +1

Comment: `box-sizing` property is awesome, it solved the problem, thanks

Comment: In case this does not work for someone, check that `line-height` is correct. For some reason it was 0 in my case and then the padding does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS to create the desired effect

```css
textarea {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the padding from CSS applied to *textarea* is correct. But then you need to change the "rows" and the "columns" as the dimensions of the whole textarea changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
line-height: _px;
```

Use the same value as the height of the textarea.

Comment: So "`_px`" is not literal(?). Perhaps use an example instead? Can you provide more context than just the single line? What could the CSS content look like? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25801006/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).